# How do I show status in a progress bar on my winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, progress-bar

While transferring data from one table to another, I want a progress bar to show status on my Form. I tried some ways but it's not working.

```
if (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1 == no_Of_rows)
{
    progressBar1.Value = 100;
    dataGridView1.Visible = true;
}
else
{
    progressBar1.Value = 50;
    dataGridView1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Show the code and tell is **what** isn't working.

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker, Look up the Class, go from there.

Comment: if (dataGridView1.RowCount - 1 == no_Of_rows)
                        {
                            progressBar1.Value = 100;
                            dataGridView1.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            progressBar1.Value = 50;
                            dataGridView1.Visible = false;
                        }

Comment: Please don't post code as a comment. Update your post (or add an answer) and use the code-tags

Answer (score 0):

Use Progress bar window control

For references :
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449594/Progress-Bars-Threads-Windows-Forms-and-You

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to use the backgroundworker.

```
private BackgroundWorker worker;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        this.worker = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true
            };
        worker.DoWork += WorkerOnDoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += WorkerOnProgressChanged;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate
            {
                //Set the value of the progressbar to the maximum value if the work is done
                this.progressBar1.Value = this.progressBar1.Maximum;
            };
        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void WorkerOnProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set the value of the progressbar, or increment it.
        //You can use the e.ProgressPercentage to get the value you set in the DoWork-Method
        //The e.UserState ist a custom-value you can pass from the DoWork-Method to this Method
        this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }


    private void WorkerOnDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do you stuff here. Here you can tell the backgroundworker to report the progress like.
        this.worker.ReportProgress(5);
        //You can not access properties from here, so if you want to pass a value or something else to the
        //progresschanged-method you have to use e.Argument. 

    }
```

It's a winforms-application. on the form there's just a progressbar named progressbar1